# Bias only Layer in Keras

Tags: keras, deep-learning

How could one build a layer in Keras which maps an input x to an output of the form x+b where b is a trainable weight of the same dimension?  (Also the activation function here would be the identity).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always build a custom layer by extending `tf.keras.layers.Layer` class, here is how I'd do it

```
import tensorflow as tf
print('TensorFlow:', tf.__version__)

class BiasLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BiasLayer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.bias = self.add_weight('bias',
                                    shape=input_shape[1:],
                                    initializer='zeros',
                                    trainable=True)
    def call(self, x):
        return x + self.bias

input_layer = tf.keras.Input(shape=[5])
x  = BiasLayer()(input_layer)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_layer], outputs=[x])

model.summary()
```

```
TensorFlow: 2.1.0
Model: "model_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_7 (InputLayer)         [(None, 5)]               0         
_________________________________________________________________
bias_layer_3 (BiasLayer)     (None, 5)                 5         
=================================================================
Total params: 5
Trainable params: 5
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Yeah it is possible, you can always add a new weight using `add_weight` method. In this case just add another weight with name say `kernel` having `shape=input_shape[1:]`. And change the `call` method to return `tf.multiply(x, self.kernel) + self.bias`

Comment: Quick question, if I also want to multiply by a trainable matrix then how should I modify the "input_shape"

[input_shape[1:],input_shape[1:]]
make sense?

Comment: use `return tf.nn.bias_add(x, self.bias)` instead of `return x + self.bias` for completeness, as per the docs: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/bias_add