# Is it possible to train a layer's weights but not its biases (or vice versa) in Keras?

Tags: keras

I know from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53503389/how-to-set-parameters-in-keras-to-be-non-trainable) that it is possible to set an entire layer as non-trainable by something like this:

```
weights_and_bias = [weight_matrix, bias_vector]
frozen_layer = Dense(32, weights=weights_and_bias, trainable=False)
```

But that will make both the weights *and* the biases untrainable. I want to be able to make one but not the other trainable.

Is there some easy to way to do this?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. However, it should be easy to just split this into two layers: Use a dense layer without biases (`Dense(use_bias=False)`), and a custom layer that only adds a bias, maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60644157/bias-only-layer-in-keras

Comment: Ah, yes, I had a vague idea something like this should be possible. So basically one layer will have weights but not a bias, then the next layer will have a bias but a weight matrix that is just the identity matrix?

Comment: Note that biases are called "weights" as well. The first layer would just have the multiplication kernel but no bias (as you say), but the second layer would not have a multiplication kernel at all, just the bias weights. I haven't tried the custom layer in the answer I linked to, but it looks like it does exactly that.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot tomorrow. I appreciate the pointer.

Comment: Forgot to update. This works! Thanks @jlh